# using dplyr() to count, having an issue

Tags: r, dplyr

This is probably a brain fart on my part but I'd like some help.

I have a data frame:

```
dftest <- data.frame(
    "id" = c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5),rep("C",5)),
    "time" = c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4),
    "val" = c(1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1))
```

I'm trying to use the data frame to find, for each time, the number of times the val column equals 2 divided by the total number of entries at that time.

So for the above data frame, for time = 0, val = 2 for id = "C", so the result would be 1/3, whereas for time 1, val = 2 for id="A" and id="B", so the result would be 2/3.

How can I do this in dplyr?

Comment: In base R, `tapply(dftest$val, dftest$time, FUN=function(i) mean(i == 2))` will return a named vector with the desired results as will `prop.table(table(dftest$val, dftest$time), 2)[2,]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find proportions using the `mean()` function on a boolean value (which is coerced to 0/1). For example

```
dftest %>% group_by(time) %>% 
    summarize(proptwo = mean(val==2))
#   A tibble: 5 × 2
#    time   proptwo
#   <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1     0 0.3333333
# 2     1 0.6666667
# 3     2 0.6666667
# 4     3 0.6666667
# 5     4 0.6666667
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be going too different a route as you would like but:

```
plyr::ldply(dftest %>% split(., .[['time']]), function(i){
    nrow(i %>% dplyr::filter(val == 2)) / nrow(i)
}) %>% select(time = 1, freq = 2)


  time      freq
1    0 0.3333333
2    1 0.6666667
3    2 0.6666667
4    3 0.6666667
5    4 0.6666667
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(proptwo = val==2)~time, dftest, mean)
#   time   proptwo
#1    0 0.3333333
#2    1 0.6666667
#3    2 0.6666667
#4    3 0.6666667
#5    4 0.6666667
```

Comment: this is really nice btw